# "Deprecation Notice" in phpMyAdmin on Centos 7

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, centos7

I have phpMyadmin installed in a VPS, but i have a lot of deprecation notice like:

1) Deprecation Notice in ./libraries/Util.class.php#1994. Array and string offset access syntax with curly braces is deprecated

2) Deprecation Notice in ./libraries/common.inc.php#261. Function get_magic_quotes_gpc() is deprecated

3) Deprecation Notice in ./libraries/url_generating.lib.php#239. Array and string offset access syntax with curly braces is deprecated

4) Deprecation Notice in ./libraries/DatabaseInterface.class.php#537. Unparenthesized `a ? b : c ? d : e` is deprecated. Use either `(a ? b : c) ? d : e` or `a ? b : (c ? d : e)`

I have:

CentOS 7.7
PHP 7.4.3
5.5.64

How can i solve this problem?, they show up each time a page is loaded or action is performed).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What version of phpMyAdmin are you running? There appears to be a php compatibility issue with php7.4

I would recommend updating phpMyAdmin to the latest version compatible with with php7.4.

https://www.phpmyadmin.net/news/2020/1/8/phpmyadmin-494-and-501-are-released/

Alternatively - and I wouldn't advocate doing this in a production environment - you could suppress deprecated messages. For example you could change the error reporting setting in your php.ini to something like:

```
error_reporting = E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED
```

Comment: I would recommend installing version 5.0.1

Comment: phpMyAdmin 4.4 hasn't been supported since 2016, you definitely should upgrade. Currently version 4.9 is in the long-term support phase to provide security support for users on PHP 5.5 through 7.0; I agree with CountKyle that 5.0.1 is the current best version if you're able to meet the requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Edit the following file : config.inc.php. It can be located in **/etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php** or in **/usr/share/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php**

```php
/**
 * Whether or not to query the user before sending the error report to
 * the phpMyAdmin team when a JavaScript error occurs
 *
 * Available options
 * ('ask' | 'always' | 'never')
 * default = 'ask'
 */

$cfg['SendErrorReports'] = 'never';
```